# How to List the certificate and copy the ARN for Mqtt broker

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS. I am trying to Bridge Mosquitto MQTT Broker to AWS IoT, in creating the certificate I failed when following these steps:

Place yourself in Mosquitto directory.

And create certificates and keys, note the certificate ARN

```
cd /etc/mosquitto/certs/
sudo aws iot create-keys-and-certificate --set-as-active --certificate-pem-outfile cert.crt --private-key-outfile private.key --public-key-outfile public.key --region eu-central-1
```

well when i ran this command i got "certificateArn","certificatepem .. etc

I failed at updating the certificate list .

List the certificate and copy the ARN in the form of

```
arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:0123456789:cert/xyzxyz
aws iot list-certificates
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-24-69 /]$ aws iot list-certificates

"certificates": []
```

It showing empty list how to add CertificateArn

And in the place of  what data I should give?

```
#Attach the policy to your certificate
aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name bridge --principal <ARN_OF_CERTIFICATE>
```

[Here is the putty(output) screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgFf2.png)

Comment: Show the whole output of the create command.

Answer (score 0):

Aws IOT certificates are created for a specific region.

Your first commands creates and activates a certificate in `eu-central-1` because you specified a region.

Your `list-certificates` command does not specify a region.

Most likely your default region is set to something other than `eu-central-1` and hence it is not showing certificates.